# How to implement soundcloud share button

Tags: android, soundcloud

How can i implement share button of [soundcloud](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) which share a link of audio track and when user click on it open this track with [soundcloud](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) application.

I searched but i didn't find any thing all of them share [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686469/sharing-audio-file) or [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android) or [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps) or [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969217/share-application-link-in-android), so any help of how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean sharing the song link from your app to another application / email / whatsapp, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345347/how-to-play-an-audio-from-soundcloud-in-our-app) for adding sound from Soundcloud app.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588543/open-soundcloud-url-in-native-soundcloud-app-from-webview) for accessing Soundcloud to play song in Soundcloud

This code from [enadun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513977/force-a-soundcloud-track-to-open-in-soundcloud-app-on-android?rq=1) may help:

```
String id = "114143409"; //Track id
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://sounds:" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```